# Movie that had a nerd kid who goes back to Arthurian period with scientific inventions and gadgets

Tags: story-identification, movie

In this movie, a boy or a teen somehow ends up in the Arthurian period. He wears glasses and has a knack with inventions and gadgets. He almost gets executed by King Arthur, but he performs a magic to block the sun and gets out, which even the fireball-hurling Merlin finds amazing. He also performs other magic such as lightning (electrical) lance in a jousting arena.

I remember other details like he worshiped Elvis Presley as the king and the source of his power, and Merlin figures out he's from the future and brings back some music from the future to party with Knights of the Round Table. I tried to find this movie on my own several times, but it is just too difficult. ["A Kid in King Arthur's Court"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113538/) looked so close, but the synopsis looks different from how I remember, and I remember the kid wore glasses all the time.

Comment: A Kid in King Arthur's Court has a scene where the titular hero uses a robotic knight to beat the baddie

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Possibly *A Young Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court* (1995).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115030/):

> Hank is a shy high school student in Connecticut who plays in a band with his friends. While trying to fix an amplifier for the band, he gets a shock and awakes in the land of a peasant. He is imprisoned by Alisande, who is the fiancée of Sir Galahad, and brought to the Court of King Arthur. **Hank lures King Arthur and Merlin using his knowledge of an eclipse** and succeeds to get a workshop to try to return to the future and Alisandre falls in love with him. Meanwhile, the evil Morgan Le Fay conspire with the knight Ulrich to overthrow King Arthur.

In the video below:

- [The kid wears glasses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8eFl.png) (4'39 for that screenshot, but they stay on for the whole movie);
- "I am going to block out the sun" (*b'dum tsss*) scene starts at 24'55. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxxO7.png);
- a witty lancer attempts to deflect an electrified weapon with a metallic shield at 1'08'20. [Doesn't end well for him](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czLla.jpg).

---

Found in the ["Connections" section of  *A Kid in King Arthur's Court*'s IMDb page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113538/movieconnections/?tab=mc&ref_=tt_trv_cnn).

Comment: "*their amazement soon passes as Arthur condemns Hank to be burnt at the stake for claiming to have come from the future. While tied to the stake, Hank'causes' the solar eclipse by naming his gods, 'Metallica, U2, Snoop Doggy Dog, and— **the greatest of them all—Elvis!** 'The eclipse has the expected effect, and Hank is released and dubbed 'Sir Dude,' by a now-thankful Arthur. In attempting to figure out how to get back home, Hank faces a challenge from Galahad, uncovers liaisons between Lancelot and Guinevere, and foils a plot by Morgan Le Faye to overthrow Arthur. As Hank finally begins..."*

Comment: How many times has this book been adapted anyway? The connections page seems to go on forever and it might lack some.

Comment: In film, probably a couple of dozen times. It's a nice easy (and cheap!) one to write because all the major iconic scenes are already plotted out for you. It's the same reason they keep making Robin Hood and the Three Musketeers

Comment: Thank you so much @Jenayah! I don't know how many times I tried to find this movie, but it never poped up for me. I was seriously wondering if I just have bad memory and imagined it up from several different similar movies. Thank you for all the links and screenshots too. You are awesome!

Comment: @Efreeto you're welcome, enjoy the rewatch! :)